# Validate duplicated entry in textfile

Tags: javascript, php

I am making an website that store user info such as (username, password, email) into a txt file. The code i have so far.

```
<?php
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
//
//the data
echo "<br>"; 
$data = "$username | $password | $email | $caesar || \n";
$fh = fopen("users.txt", "a");
fwrite($fh, $data);
fclose($fh);
print "User Submitted";
?>
```

When user fill out their details on 1st page and click Submit button , it will trigger this event and write stuffs on users.txt.

Question is :

1. How can i check if there is any duplicated entry in **users.txt**, if users type a duplicated one and press Submit, site will say like **"Duplicated"**
2. How can i display all the entry in **users.txt** in a page called as **Display.php**

I am quite new to Php, sorry if i make any mistake when coding

Thanks guys

---

thanks @user3544440

Question 1:

I have put your code into my ones, it doesnt run or maybe the order of the code was wrong

```
echo "<br>"; 
$data = "$username | $password | $email | $credit | $caesar || \n";
echo "<br>"; 

//ur code

//my code start again from here
$fh = fopen("users.txt", "a");
fwrite($fh, $data);
```

Comment: NB: Be very careful when writing to a single file like this in a web service. Keep in mind, that in a web application the same (PHP) page can be executed multiple times **simultaneously** in different threads, however a file can be only be open (and written to) by one thread at a time. So if two people try you submit the form at the same time, there is a chance one of them will fail losing the data he was posting.

Comment: They are 3 separate file. i make it for Caesar Encryption. 1 file to input user info, 1 file validate against the DB and 1 file display all info on the DB. I still have problem with writing Encrypted string into txt file. Dunno how to fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 to find duplicate entry, you have to read all file and check each line

```
$flag = 0;
$handle = fopen("user.txt", "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
        $user = explode("|", $line);
        if($user[0] == $_POST['user']){
             $flag=1;
             break;
        }
    }
} else {
    // error opening the file.
} 
fclose($handle);
if($flag==1){
    echo "duplicate entry";
}else{
    //Write user data in the file
}
```

2 For display each line use the same loop

```
$handle = fopen("user.txt", "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
        $user = explode("|", $line);
        echo "name:".$user[0];
        echo "password:".$user[1];
        echo "email:".$user[2];
    }
} else {
    // error opening the file.
} 
fclose($handle);
```

Comment: Where do i suppose to put the code for the Question1 ??. is that on the same place as the code write users info into file

Comment: @user2846896 yes you have to put the code before write user data in the file, if the variable $flag is 1 print the error and exit else write data in the file

Comment: @user2846896 i did the checking before open the file and write stuffs, but it doesnt run .

Comment: it doesn't run, mean id doesn't write in the file or there is a PHP error?

Comment: no errors, the site just said User Added. i have modified ur answer with my code. do u see it

Comment: no i don't see your edit, i suspect the problem is the whitespace you write in the file after the username and before "|", try to edit the condition with trim($user[0]) or delete it from the file

Comment: i have fix my question @user3544440 . added my code and ur code so you know what can cause the error

Comment: have you tried to change the condition to "if(trim($user[0]) == $_POST['user'])"?

Comment: hi @user3544440 , everything is ok now, thanks for help, you have any email or using chat so i can discuss more about that code in person ?